# Force keyboard re-identification in Catalina MacOS

Tags: keyboard, catalina

I switched from a Logitech keyboard to a Mac external keyboard on my macbook pro with Catalina MacOS. Every time I hit capitol M it types MZ. It could be the case that the keyboard is malfunctioning, but before I replace it I thought of trying to re-identify the keyboard and see if it helps.

[MacOS user guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/specify-a-keyboard-type-mchlp2886/mac) says this:

1. On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click
   Keyboard.
2. Click **Change Keyboard Type**, then follow the onscreen
   instructions.

However I could not find **Change Keyboard Type** in that interface - see screenshot below. I also tried [this sudo command](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1620325) but it didn't work.

How I could force a keyboard re-identification?

[image]

Comment: It’s hard to imagine any kind of wrong identification that would cause the problem you describe.

Comment: Strange, maybe because it's an Apple keyboard? Have you tried deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` and restarting? What about just adding another input source in the Input Sources tab and selecting it?

Comment: Also I agree with @TomGewecke, this sounds like a hardware failure, not a software issue. Which Apple keyboard exactly is it you're using?

Comment: I have had a case where an apple keyboard would behave exactly like that after coffee was poured over the keys...

Comment: Can you try using this keyboard on any other machine? A hardware issue wouldn't disappear when changing system

Comment: @TomGewecke After exploring various options, I agree this is a hardware failure. Please post your answer and I'll approve it :)

Answer (score 7):

I had the issue where I could not find Change Keyboard Type in that interface after migrating to new Mac with Big Sur and wanted to force keyboard re-identification.

Deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` (as suggested above by JMY1000) and rebooting solved it. After the reboot the system ran the keyboard setup again and I could set the correct type.

Comment: When you say "same issue", did you actually get two letters instead of one when you pressed the M (or any other) key?? If so, please put that specific info in your answer too. If not, you need to tell exactly what your problem was.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, no I did not get the two letters instead of one. I was referring to the ”I could not find Change Keyboard Type in that interface” part and how to solve the ”force keyboard re-identification” part.

Answer (score 2):

To force keyboard re-identification without deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` and restarting, you can re-trigger the `KeyboardSetupAssistant` from System/Library - `/System/Library/CoreServices/KeyboardSetupAssistant.app`

Using Finder:

1. Menu -> Go -> Go to folder (or Shift + CMD + G)
2. Input the path: `/System/Library/CoreServices`
3. Find and tap on `KeyboardSetupAssistant`

This have worked on macOS Ventura 13.3.1 for me

Comment: I tried this today (on Ventura 13.3.1) but when I launched the KeyboardSetupAssistant.app nothing happened. I had to fall back to the deletion and reboot again.

Comment: I'm sorry, it still works for me. A window popups and says: "Keyboard Setup Assistant", "Your Logitech device cannot be identified..."

Comment: This work as today MacOS Ventura and M1 chip (I know is not relevant, but just in case someone finds it useful)

Comment: ... same here (nothing happens from Finder) and when trying to run it from command line it crashes with "trace trap"

Answer (score 0):

Officially, only other external keyboards appear to change the keyboard type, 'Magic Keyboard' for Apple , The keyboard type is recognizable, so it won't appear .